# Any way to automagically `puts` the last expression in a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on implementing Project Euler solutions as semantic [Ruby one-liners](https://github.com/stouset/euler/). It would be extremely useful if I could coerce Ruby to automatically puts the value of the last expression. Is there a way to do this? For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -Ilib -rrubygems -reuler

1.upto(100).into {|n| (n.sum.squared - n.map(&:squared).sum)
```

I realize I can simply `puts` the line, but for other reasons (I plan to `eval` the file in tests, to compare against the expected output) I would like to avoid an explicit `puts`. Also, it allots me an extra four characters for the solution. :)

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Where would you put the `puts` in this case?

Comment: I want it to be implicit on the last expression of the file. I'm not certain it's possible, but if it is, I figured someone here would know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try running it under *irb* instead of directly under a Ruby interpreter.

It seems like the options `-f --noprompt --noverbose` might be suitable (.

```
#!/usr/bin/env irb -f --noprompt --noverbose -Ilib -rrubygems -reuler

'put your one-liner here'
```

The options have these meanings:

- `-f`: do not use `.irbrc` (or IRBRC)
- `--noverbose`: do not display the source lines
- `--noprompt`: do not prefix the output (e.g. with `=>`)

Comment: Aha! This does the trick, with only the (almost inconsequential) downside of printing an extra newline.

Answer (score 0):

result of eval is last executed operation just like any other code block in ruby

is doing

```
puts eval(file_contents)
```

an option for you?

EDIT

you can make use of eval's second parameter which is variables binding

try the following:

```
do_not_puts = true
eval(file_contents, binding)
```

and in the file:

```
....
result = final_result
if defined?(do_not_puts)
  result
else
  puts(result)
end
```

Comment: I may have been unclear. I want the contents of the file to be implicitly put's when run (similar to the `-p` flag) at the shell, but there should be no output if the file is `eval`'d

Answer (score 0):

```
result = calculate_result

puts result if File.exist?(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to change the way you run scripts?

script.rb:

```
$_= 1.upto(100).into {|n| (n.sum.squared - n.map(&:squared).sum)
```

invoke with 
`echo nil.txt | /usr/bin/env/ruby -Ilib -rrubygems -reuler -p script.rb`, where nil.txt is a file with a single newline.